# Reversing a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect accesses from:

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?sub=subdomain&type=cars
```

to

```
http://subdomain.example.com/cars
```

I already have mod_rewrite rules to do the *opposite*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/index.php?route=$1&name=%1 [R=301,L]
```

What changes do I need to make to these rules to redirect requests from the script to the subdomain?

Comment: Have you considered simply making this change in the PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sub=(.+)&type=(.*)$
RewriteRule . http://%1.example.com/%2?
```

Comment: thanks for respons but i am a another problem ::
Cette page Web présente une boucle de redirection.
input : [domain.com/test.php?sub=asdasd&type=456]
output: (http://asdasd.domain.com/456?sub=asdasd&type=456)

Comment: @KIRA remove the QSA argument in your `RewriteRule`

Comment: @KIRA ...or add question mark `?` after the `%2` w/o any white space - like this `...domain.com/%2?`